# Laravel:: reuse article id into new table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to be able to make a "like" system. I have three tables. `Users`, `Articles`, `Likes`.

In the `Articles` table I have the id, title, body. In `Likes` I have id, user_id, and article_id.

So when a person presses like on the article I fill the table with their user id and the article_id.

However I'm running into the problem of adding the id. This is basic to most I know, I have seen the `laravel` videos but its still new to me.

Here is what I have in the article controller.

```
$article = new Article();
    $article->body = 'new article body';
    $article->title = 'new article Title';
    $article->type = 'fashion';

    $article->save();

    $articles = Article::where('type', 'fashion')->get();
    //$articles = Article::all();
    return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));


 public function store()
{
    $request = Request::all();


    $likes = new like();
    $likes ->article_id = Article::find($id);
    $likes->user_id =   Auth::user()->id;
    $name = Auth::user()->name;
    $likes->save();

    $followers = new Follower();
    $followers->follower_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $followers->user_id =  $request['user_id'];
    $name = Auth::user()->name;
    $followers->save();

    return redirect('article');



}
```

Comment: Can you tell us if there is an error, what kind of error? Also have you tried to use `Like::create`

Comment: it tells me that the $id : Undefined variable: id

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with `Auth::user` maybe the user trying to do it is not authenticated or the ->id is not available on that object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable which doesn't exist. Variable `$id` being used on this line

`$likes ->article_id = Article::find($id);`

is not initialized anywhere. Maybe you are expecting it to be on the Request? So in that case, `$request->id` in that case.

Also if your model is called `Like` than you should fix the case on this line `$likes = new like();` to `$likes = new Like();`.